# Updating container (binary blob) to FileMaker via pyodbc

Tags: python, odbc, filemaker

I want to UPDATE an image in a local FileMaker database using the ODBC connection.

I expected that the following code would work, but it fails:

```
import pyodbc

with open('myimage.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    img = f.read()
# ensure we have a valid image
assert isinstance(img, bytes)
assert len(img) == 10506

dsn = 'DRIVER=/Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so;Server=127.0.0.1;Port=2399;Database=MyDatabase;UID=Admin;PWD='
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(dsn)
cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='macroman')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

q = "UPDATE MyTable SET PutAs(Image, 'JPEG')=? WHERE Id=?"
cursor.execute(q, img, 37370)
```

It raises an exception: `ProgrammingError: '42000', '[42000] [FileMaker][FileMaker] FQL0001/(1:18): There is an error in the syntax of the query. (8310) (SQLPrepare)'`.

Reading an images with `SELECT GetAs(Image, 'JPEG') FROM MyTable WHERE Id=37370)` works fine. I receive a bytes objects which is the image.

Comment: Note that the "syntax error" may mean just about anything. For example, it is also raised if the encoding is incorrect: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/89. That may be case here too, but I wouldn't know how to set the encoding any better than this.

Comment: I see two -1 votes. If you think this is a bad question, please let me know why, so I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for binary insert in FileMaker ODBC is not good, next to non-existing.

I would suggest you base64 your image and insert it as text, with FileMaker decoding it back into an image

Comment: Thanks, I asked the same question on the FileMaker forum and got the same answer. I did look at other interfaces to FileMaker (Data API, XML interface), but those explicitly did not support containers. It seems that JDBC might support containers, but Python-JDBC does not seem very common (I only found one older library).